# the echo reply time of ICMP ping become shorter and shorter

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, ping, icmp

I wrote a program to ping anther server, it worked well(ping were successful, the peer server could get the ping and rely the ping), but my confusion is that why the response time become shorter and shorter, the response time were around 100ms before, after a few seconds the response time become 2ms or 1ms.

The log printed as following:

```
from 10.9.9.9 msg_seq=1 ttl=64 rtt = 100 ms 
from 10.9.9.9 msg_seq=2 ttl=64 rtt = 102 ms 
from 10.9.9.9 msg_seq=3 ttl=64 rtt = 101 ms 
from 10.9.9.9 msg_seq=4 ttl=64 rtt = 100 ms 
........//after a few sencondes
from 10.9.9.9 msg_seq=280 ttl=64 rtt = 1 ms 
from 10.9.9.9 msg_seq=281 ttl=64 rtt = 2 ms 
from 10.9.9.9 msg_seq=282 ttl=64 rtt = 0 ms
```

The code as following please:

```
#define PING_PKT_S 64
#define PORT_NO 0
#define PING_SLEEP_RATE 1000000
#define RECV_TIMEOUT 1

int pingloop=1;

struct ping_pkt {
    struct icmphdr hdr;
    char msg[PING_PKT_S-sizeof(struct icmphdr)];
};

unsigned short checksum(void *b, int len) {
    unsigned short *buf = b;
    unsigned int sum=0;
    unsigned short result;

    for ( sum = 0; len > 1; len -= 2 )
        sum += *buf++;
    if ( len == 1 )
        sum += *(unsigned char*)buf;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    result = ~sum;
    return result;
}


void intHandler(int dummy) {
    pingloop=0;
}

long current_timestamp() {
    struct timeval te;
    gettimeofday(&te, NULL);
    long milliseconds = te.tv_sec*1000LL + te.tv_usec/1000;
    return milliseconds;
}


void display(void *buf, int bytes){
    int i;
    for ( i = (sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct icmphdr)); i < bytes; i++ ){
        printf("%c", ((unsigned char*)buf)[i]);
    }
}

// make a ping request
void send_ping(int ping_sockfd, char *ping_ip) {
    int ttl_val=64, msg_count=0, i, addr_len, msg_received_count=0;

    struct ping_pkt pckt;
    struct sockaddr_in r_addr;
    struct timespec time_start, time_end;
    // set socket options at ip to TTL and value to 64,
    if (setsockopt(ping_sockfd, SOL_IP, IP_TTL,  &ttl_val, sizeof(ttl_val)) != 0) {
        printf("Setting socket options to TTL failed!\n");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("\nSocket set to TTL..\n");
    }
    // send icmp packet in an infinite loop
    while(pingloop) {
        if(isActiveNow()){
            printf("--current is active!\n");
            sleep(5);
            continue;
        }
        //filling packet
        bzero(&pckt, sizeof(pckt));

        pckt.hdr.type = ICMP_ECHO;
        pckt.hdr.un.echo.id = getpid();

        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
            pckt.msg[i] = 'w';
        }
        pckt.msg[i] = 0;
        pckt.hdr.un.echo.sequence = msg_count++;
        pckt.hdr.checksum = checksum(&pckt, sizeof(pckt));

        long s1 = current_timestamp();
        struct hostent *hostentObj;
        hostentObj = gethostbyname(ping_ip);
        struct sockaddr_in ping_addr;
        ping_addr.sin_port = 0;
        ping_addr.sin_family = hostentObj->h_addrtype;
        ping_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*) hostentObj->h_addr;

        //Using synchronize
        if ( sendto(ping_sockfd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt), 0,  (struct sockaddr*) &ping_addr, sizeof(ping_addr)) <= 0) {
            printf("\nPacket Sending Failed!\n");
        }

        struct timeval tv_out;
        tv_out.tv_sec = 10;
        tv_out.tv_usec = 0;

        struct sockaddr_in peerAddr;
        unsigned char buf[1024];
        int len=sizeof(peerAddr);

        bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));
        int bytes_received = recvfrom(ping_sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&peerAddr, &len);
        if (bytes_received > 0) {
          printf("ICMP packet received from %s\n", inet_ntoa(peerAddr.sin_addr));
          struct icmphdr *icmp = (struct icmphdr *) (buf + sizeof(struct iphdr));
          switch (icmp->type) {
              case ICMP_ECHOREPLY:{
                  printf("Type: ICMP_ECHO--REPLY----------\n");
                  long s2 = current_timestamp();
                  printf("from %s msg_seq=%d ttl=%d rtt = %ld ms \n", ping_ip, msg_count,ttl_val, (s2-s1));
                  display(buf, bytes_received);
                  break;
              };
              case ICMP_DEST_UNREACH:{
                  printf("Type: ICMP_DEST_UNREACH---WRONG\n");
                  failedNum++;
                  break;
              }
              case ICMP_SOURCE_QUENCH:  printf("Type: ICMP_SOURCE_QUENCH\n"); break;
              case ICMP_REDIRECT:       printf("Type: ICMP_REDIRECT\n"); break;
              case ICMP_ECHO:{
                  printf("Type: ICMP_ECHO-----\n");
                  long s2 = current_timestamp();
                  printf("from %s msg_seq=%d ttl=%d rtt = %ld ms \n", ping_ip, msg_count,ttl_val, (s2-s1));
                  display(buf, bytes_received);
                  break;
              }
              default: printf("Type: <0x%02x>\n", icmp->type); break;
          }
        }
    }
}

// Driver Code
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockfd;
    char myIp[64]="10.1.1.10";
    char *peerIp = "10.9.9.9";

    sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    struct sockaddr_in r_addr;
    r_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    r_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(myIp);
    r_addr.sin_port = 0;

    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &r_addr, sizeof(r_addr));

    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);//catching interrupt

    //send pings continuously
    send_ping(sockfd,  peerIp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, which is a low priority. Devices, e.g. routers, switches, hosts, servers, printers, firewalls, etc., all have functions which take priority. For example, you want your router to route packets as fast as possible. ICMP message generation is typically a very low priority, and the device will get around to sending an ICMP message when it gets time.

Comment: If `bytes_received` is `0` you will go to next iteration  resetting the `s1`

Comment: @EugeneSh. It doesn't matter, the s1 should be resetting in each iteration, as long as the s2 is correct when the bytes_received>0. Actually bytes_received always bigger than 0 in all of my test cases.

Comment: But you never check if the reply was complete. It could be only a partial reply, then the subsequent iteration will receive the next part of previous reply (which will probably happen faster than the actual reply).

Comment: @EugeneSh. it makes sense, how to check the completion please? Could you give a sample code, thanks!

Comment: No, I don't have any code and I am not very well versed in this subject. I would think that you should know the size of the expected response and check against it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think this line: int bytes_received = recvfrom(ping_sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&peerAddr, &len); Already finished the check, otherwise it would not return anything. There is no half package at all.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom You are passing `0` as flags. But there is `MSG_WAITALL` flag which will instruct it to block until the full length is received. *The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested.*

Comment: But you are requesting size of 1024 bytes. I doubt it is the right size for the ICMP response.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The ICMP response should be the same size as the ICMP request.

Comment: How do your response times compare to using the real `ping` command?

Comment: @Barmar I would say the first one should be close to the right one, as it is really measuring time between the first request and first response

Comment: @Barmar the Ping command always keep 100ms response time. After taking EugeneSh's suggestion I added WAITALL in recvfrom(), it turns good. But the response time switches between 100ms and 30ms, it's weird, I'm checking if there is  WaitAll in sendto.

Comment: @Jack You need to adjust the expected response length per Barmars suggestion. Your request length doesn't seem to match to the response

Comment: @EugeneSh.  I tried Barmar's advice, and  I changed the size to 64,but it still response too fast. It's weird that if I sleep one second before the function sendto, the response time become 0ms. not sure if my current_timestamp has problem.